# Integrating OrgChart with Vaadin 7

Tags: gwt, vaadin7

Does anyone know how to integrate the gwt orgchart widget with vaadin 7? I've followed the steps given in the first and second part of this tutorial http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-gwt-widgets-vaadin-7 but I'm stuck right now. I don't really understand the communication between classes or what are the methods that I need to override.

I know that the Lexaden Organization Chart Addon already integrates the widget with vaadin 7, but after compiling the widgetset and restarting the application I got this error:

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for com.lexaden.business.chart.OrganizationalChart. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset.
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance,
Matías

Comment: Did you perform the steps that are suggested in the error message?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I checked the .gwt.xml widgetset file and I only found this line 
<inherits name="com.lexaden.business.chart.widgetset.OrganisationWidgetset" />